# How to create dynamic bookmark in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

Is it possible, or how to do it - to have bookmark (bookmarklet?) that, when clicking would open new page, that would have 2 parameters calculated based on current date?

For example, today it would open:

```
http://some.site/page?from=2011-11-01&to=2011-11-28
```

but in a week it would be

```
http://some.site/page?from=2011-12-01&to=2011-12-05
```

Comment: Can't rattle off a specific solution off the top of my head, but yes, a JavaScript bookmarklet should be able to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the opportunity to learn something! Here's what I came up with. Create a bookmark with the following in the Location field.

```
javascript:function z() { var d = new Date(); ym = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-'; return 'http://some.site/page?from='+ym+'01&to='+ym+d.getDate(); } window.open(z(),"_blank");
```

It looks like you wanted from the first of the current month to the current date, correct?